# Error when sql querying multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have to query multiple tables (`tcountry, tcity, tcompany, temployee`) to get a final answer with countries/cities/populations/companies/number of employees included. Somewhere I must be making a mistake.

Tables `tcountry` and `tcity` have one column with the same name (`country_name`), tables `tcity` and `tcompany` have also both one column with the same name (`city_name`), tables `tcompany` and `temployee` have both one column with same name (`company_name`).

Query:

```
SELECT 
    tcountry.country_name AS country, 
    tcountry.country_population AS population1,
    tcity.city_name AS city, 
    tcity.city_population AS population2,
    tcompany.company_name AS company,
    COUNT AS (*) employee 
FROM 
    temployee 
INNER JOIN 
    tcity ON temployee.company_city_name = tcity.city 
INNER JOIN 
    tcountry ON tcity.country_name = tcountry.country
ORDER BY 
    number_of_employees
```

Comment: You are listing a column from `tcompany` in your list of columns of the `SELECT` command - but the table `tcompany` isn't shown in any of the `JOIN` statements .....

Comment: You haven't listed your RDBMS - most will throw a syntax error as you have no `GROUP BY`.  Since you don't seem to need anything but the count of employees, you could do the grouping by `company_name` in a table-reference subquery, which should be able to use an index on that column (as opposed to your current query, where the resulting `GROUP BY` would be too wide to do so).  Note that for information that sometimes changes - like a company's name - it's usually best to introduce a `surrogate key`, usually a number, to refer to/join with instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
COUNT AS (*) employee
```

should be

```
COUNT(*) AS  employee
```

Moreover, I believe you mean to say `COUNT(*) AS  number_of_employees`

As marc_s have already pointed; your are not joining with `tcompany` even though you are fetching one column from that table.

Your query should look like

```
SELECT 
    tcountry.country_name AS country, 
    tcountry.country_population AS population1,
    tcity.city_name AS city, 
    tcity.city_population AS population2,
    tcompany.company_name AS company,
    COUNT(*) AS number_of_employees <-- Here
FROM 
    temployee 
INNER JOIN 
    tcity ON temployee.company_city_name = tcity.city 
INNER JOIN 
    tcountry ON tcity.country_name = tcountry.country
INNER JOIN tcompany 
ON tcompany.company_name = temployee.company_name <-- assumption 
ORDER BY 
    number_of_employees
```

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. For some reason I`m getting now the answers where the number of employees is 2x bigger as it should be (there are 5 employees in company X in city Y, but I get 10 etc). Any ideas?

Comment: @user3625305, that's can't be answered without seeing sample data. most probably either country/city is repeated. Moreover, that's altogether a separate question and should be posted separately. I would suggest you close this thread and post a separate question with all the table schema as well as few sample data from all the tables involved in the query. Also, don't forget to accept this answer.